# How to open an extension through gestures?

Tags: 20.04

Specifically, I am trying to map the three finger swipe up to open the calendar widget. Is there any way?

Comment: What are you swiping with?

Comment: libinput, I followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@kaigo/mac-like-gestures-on-ubuntu-20-04-dell-xps-15-7ea6e3be7f76

Comment: I guess I was not clear what is the hardware?

Comment: Its a hp 15s laptop running ryzen7. I am setting up the gestures to work with its multitouch touchpad. https://store.hp.com/in-en/default/personal-laptops-hp-15s